# s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content is invalid. Element 'attribute' is invalid, misplaced, or occurs too often

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation

I have this XML for an XSD it is all good except for one error:

> Ln 25 Col 50 - s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of
>   '#AnonType_tracks' is invalid. Element 'attribute' is invalid,
>   misplaced, or occurs too often.

**Here is my XML code:**

```
<items xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="items.xsd">
<item>
  <title>Kind of Blue</title>
  <priceus>US: $11.99</priceus>
  <priceuk>UK: £8.39</priceuk>
  <artist>Miles Davis</artist>
  <tracks>
     <track length="9:22">So What</track>
     <track length="5:37">Blue in Green</track>
     <track length="11:33">All Blues</track>
     <track length="9:26">Flamenco Sketches</track>
  </tracks>
</item>
<item>
  <title>Blue Train</title>
  <priceus>US: $8.99</priceus>
  <priceuk>UK: £6.29</priceuk>
  <artist>John Coltrane</artist>
  <tracks>
     <track length="10:39">Blue Train</track>
     <track length="9:06">Moment's Notice</track>
     <track length="7:11">Locomotion</track>
  </tracks>
</item>
</items>
```

**Here is my XSD:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="title" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="priceus" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="priceuk" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="artist" type="xs:string" />
<xs:attribute name="track" type="xs:string" />

<xs:element name="tracks">
  <xs:complexType>
     <xs:simpleContent>
        <xs:attribute ref="track" use="required" />
     </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>

<xs:element name="item">
  <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="title" />
        <xs:element ref="priceus" />
        <xs:element ref="priceuk" />
        <xs:element ref="artist" />
        <xs:element ref="tracks"/>
     </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="items">
  <xs:complexType>
     <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="item" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
     </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 3):

`<xs:simpleContent>` declarations cannot contain `<attribute>` declarations, only `<restriction>` or `<extension>`.  Attributes can be specified within the `<restriction>` or `<extension>` blocks.

See https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/xml-schema/0596002521/re49.html

Comment: This points to a key part of the solution -- how to add attributes to elements with simple content (+1) -- but there's more: [*`track` is not an attribute at all but an element*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41031463/290085).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to  [Jim Garrison's correct answer about adding attributes to simple content elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41031116/290085), another problem is that for your XML, `track` is an ***element***, not an ***attribute***.

So change,

```
<xs:attribute name="track" type="xs:string" />

<xs:element name="tracks">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:attribute ref="track" use="required" />
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

to

```
<xs:element name="track">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string">
        <xs:attribute name="length" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="tracks">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="track" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

and your XSD will successfully validate your XML.